# Css horizontal menu in absolute positioned fixed width div

Tags: html, css

I am creating a navigation menu that is vertical with a horizontal submenu.

The Html:

```
<div id="sidenav">
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="option">
        <span class="label">Home</span>
    </li>
    <li class="option">
        <span class="label">About</span>
    </li>
    <li class="option">
        <span class="label">More...</span>
        <div class="submenu">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="option">
                    <span class="label">First</span>
                </li>
                <li class="option">
                    <span class="label">Second</span>
                </li>
                <li class="option">
                    <span class="label">Thrid</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The Css:

```
#sidenav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}

.menu { 
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.option {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

#sidenav > .menu > .option {
    position: relative;
}

#sidenav > .menu > .option > .submenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

#sidenav > .menu > .option > .submenu > .menu > .option {
    float: left;
}
```

Both menus are absolutely positioned and the submenu needs to be to the right of the parent menu option.

I added a float left to each menu option in the submenu but they stay vertical and won't go horizontal. How do I get the submenu to be horizontal?

You can see the result in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vS9dY/1/

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/9yMxt/

Comment: @JoshCrozier Yes but in your example you specified a width for the submenu. I can't specify the width of each submenu since they might all have different amount of items...

Comment: This is the only alternative I can think of - http://jsfiddle.net/5MXtb/ - no width required.

Comment: @JoshCrozier seems like a hack to use position fixed. Why does that even work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/vS9dY/7/

**Explanation**: Very simple,

1. On `#sidenav > .menu > .option > .submenu > .menu > .option`,
   remove `float:left;` and apply `display:inline-block;` to it.
2. On `.menu` apply `white-space:nowrap;` to prevent the `inline-block` `.option`s from wrapping to the next line.
3. Apply `line-height:50px;` to `.option`s to vertically center the text.

So:

```
.menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.option {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height:50px;
    text-align: center;
}

#sidenav > .menu > .option > .submenu > .menu > .option {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Why does the combination of white-space: nowrap on the menu and display:inline-block on the options prevent the options from going horizontal?

Comment: @DamirBojan I added some explanation to the answer on how it works.

Comment: @Arbel (superfluous?) I just wanted you to be notified of my answer.

Comment: And if I have many items in submenu? I want to, if the next item is out of screen, so it goes to next line. How do this?
http://jsfiddle.net/9DfVF/

Answer (score 0):

"Very simple" - Awesome is the better adjective.
I've enjoyed this Q&A, +1 & thanks to both.

```
list-style-type: none;
```

led me to see if divs would give the same result.  They do.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#sidenav    
  { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; width:100px; 
    background:#ccc; outline:1px dashed black; }
/* - - - - using lists - - - - */
ul  
  { list-style-type:none; padding:0; margin:0; }
ul
  { white-space:nowrap; }
li
  { width:100px; height:50px; line-height:50px; text-align:center; }
.ulmenu > li
  { position:relative; background:#fdd; }
.subulmenu      
  { position:absolute; top:0; left:100px; background:#dfd; }
.subulmenu > li
  { display:inline-block; background:#ddf; }
/* - - - - using divs - - - - */
.divmenu 
  { white-space:nowrap; }
.divmenu > div, .subdivmenu > div  
  { width:100px; height:50px; line-height:50px; text-align:center; }
.divmenu > div
  { position:relative; background:#fdd; }
.subdivmenu      
  { position:absolute; top:0; left:100px; background:#dfd; }
.subdivmenu > div
  { display:inline-block; background:#ddf; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sidenav">
  <ul class="ulmenu"><!-- using lists -->
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>More...
      <ul class="subulmenu">
        <li>First</li>
        <li>Second</li>
        <li>Thrid</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="divmenu"><!-- using divs -->
    <div>Home2</div>
    <div>About2</div>
    <div>More2...
      <div class="subdivmenu">
        <div>First2</div>
        <div>Second2</div>
        <div>Thrid2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```